# Post message to Slack when task is marked as completed in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, slack, slack-api

I created a bot that updates automatically a Google sheet whenever a message is posted in a specific Slack channel.

Now I want to send a message back to Slack whenever a task is marked as completed in the spreadsheet.

I thought to run a loop through a specific column to check on every edit if the value of any cell in that column has changed to 'completed' and send the text in that row to Slack.

The problem I can't solve is how to check if a specific message has been marked as 'completed' in the past and don't send that message to slack.

Any suggestions?

```
    var SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL= "";

function pushToSlack() {
  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data  = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  data.splice(parseInt(0), 1);  // remove the first header row
  for (var i in data) {
    var indicator = data[i][1];
    var update  = data[i][2];
    var ongoing    = data[i][6];
    if (!ongoing) { continue; } 
    sendToSlack(indicator,update,ongoing);
  }
}

function sendToSlack(indicator,update,ongoing) {

  var payload = {
    "text" : ":update_" + indicator + ": ISSUE RESOLVED:" + update 
  };
  var options =  {
    "method" : "post",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  // push to slack channel 
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of bookkeeping about which completed messages have already been sent back to Slack. One way to go about it is to use a hidden (and protected) column in the google sheet to mark messages that have already been sent.